# How to override Java container URL mappings for deployed apps

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, glassfish, admin

If I have a WAR called `my-web-app.war` and I deploy it to Tomcat's `webapps/` directory, assuming it starts up correctly, I could access it by pointing my browser at:

```
http://localhost/my-web-app
```

Likewise, if I have an EAR called `my-server-app.ear` and I deploy it to GlassFish's `domain/autodeploy/` directory, then also assuming it starts up correctly, I could access it by pointing my browser at:

```
http://localhost/my-server-app
```

But what if I want to keep my WAR/EAR with the same name, but have it deploy to URLs that are different than these defaults. For example:

- Make `my-web-app.war` deploy as `http://localhost/webapp`
- Make `my-server-app.war` deploy as `http://localhost/srvapp`
- Make `my-server-app.war` deploy as just `http://localhost`

In other servers like Apache I know it is possible to setup "virtual directories", etc., so that `http://example.com/some/long/path/to/file.html` displays in the browser as `http://example.com/file`, and was wondering if Tomcat/GlassFish allow this (and if so, how)?

I ask because I intend to have the versions of all my WARs/EARs included with their names, so I can look at them on the file system and instantly know what version they are, like:

- `my-web-app-3.17.2.war`, etc.

And making my users go to `http://localhost/my-web-app-3.17.2` seems a *little* crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Tomcat there a couple of ways of doing this but the nicest is to take advantage of the parallel deployment version label.

You would name your WAR something like:

```
webapp##my-web-app-3.17.2.war
```

and it would be deployed to

```
/webapp
```

Anything after the ## is treated as the version label for parallel deployment. See the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - what about GlassFish? I'm not seeing anything crop up in the docs when searching for "parallel deployment" so it must be a Tomcat term...

Comment: Sorry, no idea regarding GlassFish. I don't keep tabs on what that project is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an EAR you can set the context root in the file application.xml

For each war you can set a context-root